# Dynamically update the page right after API returns data

Tags: angularjs

I'm having trouble figuring out how to add an entry to my page right after the API call is done in Angular.

This is my HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="apiCtrl">
  <div class="random-articles">
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchTerm">
    <button class="btn">Search</button>
    <button id="click" ng-click="fireAPICalls()">Click me!</button>
    <div ng-repeat="article in wikiArticles">{{article.title}}</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And my JS:

```
function apiCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.wikiArticles = [];
  $scope.wikiAPI = (function(){
    return {
      getRandomArticle : function() {
        return $.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&prop=extracts&exintro=&format=json&callback=?", function (data) {});
      }
    }
  })();
  $scope.fireAPICalls = function() {
    $scope.wikiAPI.getRandomArticle().done(function(data) {
      var article;
      for(var id in data.query.pages) {
        article = data.query.pages[id];
        $scope.wikiArticles.push(article);
      }
      console.log(article);
      setTimeout($scope.fireAPICalls, 500);
    });
  }
}
```

Right now `article.title` is only updated when the "Click me!" button is clicked. Instead, I want the titles to appear after every response from the server.

How can I do that?

Comment: You mean the list of article titles is not updated, if the `setTimeout` call triggers?

Comment: @peaceman The `$scope.wikiArticles` array updates, but it doesn't show up in the DOM until the button is clicked again. Then it just dumps the current array. Instead, I want it to update the DOM every time a new article is pulled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `setTimeout` in a angular application is problematic. Then the function, that is called from `setTimeout` won't trigger a digest cycle. To prevent this, use angulars [timeout service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout).

Comment: I wasn't sure where to look, but now that I know I need to use $timeout, it works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: One more question: right now the DOM gets updated once the response from the next call has returned. How do I get it to update on the current one? For example: The first title only shows after the 2nd title has come back.

Comment: Who triggers the first call to `fireAPICalls`?

Comment: The "Click Me!" button

Comment: When the first call to `fireAPICalls` originates in a promise from jquery, we have the same problem as with `setTimeout`, it won't trigger a digest cycle. To fix this, we have to manually trigger one. Take a look at the following jsbin http://jsbin.com/IDIfEJUK/2/edit?js,console,output